# Reducing the size of a java project when exporting it to an ".exe"-Application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, exe

I currently have to take care of a Java Project (JavaFX 8). The application is finished, but my boss wants an `.exe` file, to click on and run the thing.

I built the `.exe` app from the Java source code with IntelliJ IDEA, but the folder with all the `.dll` files is huge (the `.exe` itself is tiny). My question is, if someone has experience in reducing the size of the folder, or if there is a way to make a single small `.exe` file.

The folder structure looks like:

```
|> FOLDER "app" (jar and config file)
|> FOLDER "runtime" (very huge)
    |>bin
    |>lib
|>some .dll and the .exe
```

I understand the I somehow need the JRE with the `.exe` file but maybe there still is a way to reduce the size of the runtime folder since the app itself is "pretty tiny".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the JRE to be packed with it you can use

[Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

It is not free though.

If you just need to package your Jar with little overhead you can use

[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

You need to supply your own JRE with it though.